# Remove space in front of simple question mark in: (?)

Tags: typography, kerning, french

Following, french typographic rules, LaTeX inserts a space in front of a question mark `?`. No problem.

However, for the following sequence, `(?)`, LaTeX sets a space in front of the question mark and is rendered as: `( ?)`

I've tried by preceding the question mark with a `\-` (it worked for question mark at the beginning of a line).

How can we get rid of the extra space?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `\string?`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}

\begin{document}

Une question? Peut-être.~(\string?)

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Indeed, it is much more "élégant !" Thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

By asking the question I've found the answer with by following the info about kerning tag :-D.

Preceding the question mark with `\!\,` does the job:

- `\?` is a negative space removing a given amount of space (too much here), the question mark gets sticked to the opening parenthesis `(`
- `\,` adds a tiny space in order to translate a bit the question mark away from the opening parenthesis

Sometimes, it requires to be set in math mode:  `($\!\,?)`.